# Python testing Flask API with unittest gives 404

Tags: python, python-unittest

My flask API works, I can go to my IP http://192.168.0.196:5003 and I will se "Hello - welcome to my API".

What doesn't work is writing a unittest that goes to the index and gets a HTTP 200 code. I have tried to write this test, however it gets a 404 server error code.

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask

class Main:
    app = Flask(__name__)

    def __init__(self):
        @self.app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
        def __index():
            return self.index()

    def index(self):
        return "Hello - welcome to my API"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5003)
```

**test_main.py**

```
import unittest

from src.main import Main


class MainTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.ctx = Main.app.app_context()
        self.ctx.push()
        self.client = Main.app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.ctx.pop()

    # test index #
    def test_index(self):
        """ Test index page of the flask API """

        response = self.client.get("/")
        print(f"response.status_code={response.status_code}")

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**Ouput from test:**

```
Ran 1 test in 0.007s

FAILED (failures=1)
response.status_code=404


200 != 404

Expected :404
Actual   :200
<Click to see difference>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bruker\PycharmProjects\firewalls-block-list\test\test_main.py", line 23, in test_index
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200






Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I think you don't call the Main.__init__() in the tests, so the route is not added.

Comment: @eagr: aha, off course.. By editing my test setup to "main = Main()" then "self.ctx = main.app.app_context()" it works. Thanks!